# Zombie, NWJS Module did not self-register

Tags: node.js, module, zombie.js

I'm trying to create a nwjs app with Zombiejs, but when I try to `require` Zombie, I get the following error:

```
[6355:0225/115115:ERROR:nw_shell.cc(325)] Error: Module did not self-register.
    at Error (native)
    at Module.load (module.js:346:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:356:17)
    at require (module.js:375:17)
    at bindings (/path/to/app/node_modules/zombie/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:76:44)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/path/to/app/node_modules/zombie/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify/lib/contextify.js:1:96)
    at Module._compile (module.js:451:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:469:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:346:32)
[6355:0225/115115:INFO:CONSOLE(83)] "Uncaught Error: Module did not self-register.", source: /path/to/appp/node_modules/zombie/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js (83)
```

I'm running Node.js 0.10.33 and the latest versions of nwjs and zombie. I tried upgrading to Node 0.12 but got the same error.

Comment: Did you find anything more about this?

Comment: No but see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28771245/