# Module version mismatch with headless browser and desktop Node

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, zombie.js, nw.js, electron

I'm getting a "Module version mismatch error" when I try to use a headless browser with a desktop Node shell. I've tried Zombiejs and Phantomjs with both nw.js and atom-shell; in both cases as soon as the headless browser comes into play the application crashes with a module mismatch error.

Here's the error with Phantomjs and atom-shell:

```
Uncaught Exception:
Error: Module version mismatch. Expected 41, got 14.
    at Error (native)
    at Object.module.(anonymous function) (ATOM_SHELL_ASAR.js:118:20)
    at Object.module.(anonymous function) [as .node] (ATOM_SHELL_ASAR.js:118:20)
    at Module.load (module.js:370:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:325:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:380:17)
    at require (module.js:399:17)
    at bindings (/Users/Ajay/Projects/atom-shell/node_modules/phantom/node_modules/dnode/node_modules/weak/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:76:44)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Ajay/Projects/atom-shell/node_modules/phantom/node_modules/dnode/node_modules/weak/lib/weak.js:7:35)
    at Module._compile (module.js:475:26)
```

Any idea what's causing the error?

Comment: Try running `script/bootstrap` => `script/build` on your console... does it help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is thrown from [Node.js internals](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.12.0/src/node.cc#L2028-L2036). You are mixing binary modules built for different versions of io.js or Node.js. The module version refers to the C++ `NODE_MODULE_VERSION` macro, which is accessible in JavaScript as `process.versions.modules`.

14 seems to be the version number for Node.js since Node.js v0.11.11.

<strike>I can't find any information on 41</strike>, although it is clear that 42 is the version number used by [io.js v1.0.0](https://github.com/iojs/io.js/commit/42ebdcbff1b0846c8e2d291ee320c5e0fcfcb09e).

**UPDATE**: 41 is the version of io.js bundled in [atom-shell](https://github.com/atom/node/commit/70498428ced2b8ae4ce020051f06d104b5c6c4de) internally, which is cut from io.js `v1.0.0-pre`.

nw.js/atom-shell is using its own copy of Node.js to execute the engine. In a terminal, try doing a clean installation and execution without going to atom-shell.

Also note that this problem should not be exclusive to Phantom.js or Zombie.js, but to all modules using C++ code.

To solve this problem, use one of the following instructions:

- atom-shell offers a [tutorial](https://github.com/atom/atom-shell/blob/master/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules.md) for using native modules.
- nw.js also has a [tutorial](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Build-native-modules-with-nw-gyp)

Comment: I have tried the code without atom shell or nwjs and it works well. Was wondering if there's a way to run them both?

Comment: Ah, finally found where the 41 came from. Answer updated. @apparatix I don't use atom-shell or nw.js, but basically you either need to use the same Node.js version when installing the module as nw.js/atom-shell is using, or install a module from nw.js/atom-shell. For example, atom-shell has a custom [apm](https://github.com/atom/atom-shell/blob/master/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules.md) command designed just for this kind of purposes.

Comment: I got `Module version mismatch. Expected 46, got 14.` 
What does it mean?

Comment: @hellboy similar situation: you are using node.js 0.12 (or 0.11) to install the native module but you are using atom-shell. Use `apm` to install the module.