# PM2 throws errors w/ Express app port listener and phantomjs-node instance

Tags: node.js, express, phantomjs, pm2

So I have an express app that is listening on `localhost:8888`, and if I run it in node, standalone, it listens just fine.  But when I try to run it using PM2, I get the errors below in the PM2 logs.

```
var
    phantom = require('phantom'),
    express = require('express'),
    serve = express();

phantom.create(function(ph) {
    console.log('Phantom browser created.');
    serve.get('/foo', function (req, res) {
        res.json({foo: 'bar'});
        res.end();
    });

    serve.listen(8888);
});
```

`pm2 start -i 0 myserver.js`

PM2 shows that it starts 8 processes but then if I do `pm2 list` nothing is there.

Looking in `pm2 logs` I see the errors in the log below.  BUT.. if I comment out the `serve.listen(8888);` line, it works JUST FINE.  What in the world am I doing wrong here??

```
PM2: 2015-05-27 17:16:14: Starting execution sequence in -cluster mode- for app name:myserver id:0
PM2: 2015-05-27 17:16:14: App name:myserver id:0 online
PM2: 2015-05-27 17:16:14: Starting execution sequence in -cluster mode- for app name:myserver id:1
PM2: 2015-05-27 17:16:14: App name:myserver id:1 online
PM2: 2015-05-27 17:16:14: Starting execution sequence in -cluster mode- for app name:myserver id:2
PM2: 2015-05-27 17:16:14: App name:myserver id:2 online
PM2: 2015-05-27 17:16:14: Starting execution sequence in -cluster mode- for app name:myserver id:3
PM2: 2015-05-27 17:16:14: App name:myserver id:3 online
PM2: 2015-05-27 17:16:14: Starting execution sequence in -cluster mode- for app name:myserver id:4
PM2: 2015-05-27 17:16:14: App name:myserver id:4 online
PM2: 2015-05-27 17:16:14: Starting execution sequence in -cluster mode- for app name:myserver id:5
PM2: 2015-05-27 17:16:14: App name:myserver id:5 online
PM2: 2015-05-27 17:16:14: Starting execution sequence in -cluster mode- for app name:myserver id:6
PM2: 2015-05-27 17:16:14: App name:myserver id:6 online
PM2: 2015-05-27 17:16:14: Starting execution sequence in -cluster mode- for app name:myserver id:7
PM2: 2015-05-27 17:16:15: App name:myserver id:7 online
myserver-1 (out): Phantom broswer created.
myserver-3 (out): Phantom broswer created.
myserver-5 (out): Phantom broswer created.
myserver-1 (out): Phantom broswer created.
PM2: 2015-05-27 17:16:17: [PM2] Error caught by domain:
PM2: AssertionError: false == true
PM2:     at RoundRobinHandle.add (cluster.js:140:3)
PM2:     at queryServer (cluster.js:480:12)
PM2:     at Worker.onmessage (cluster.js:438:7)
PM2:     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (cluster.js:692:8)
PM2:     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:129:20)
PM2:     at handleMessage (child_process.js:324:10)
PM2:     at Pipe.channel.onread (child_process.js:352:11)
myserver-7 (out): Phantom broswer created.
myserver-3 (out): Phantom broswer created.
PM2: 2015-05-27 17:16:17: [PM2] Automatic `pm2 update` failed. Killing PM2 daemon and its processes...
PM2: 2015-05-27 17:16:17: pm2 has been killed by signal, dumping process list before exit...
PM2: 2015-05-27 17:16:17: Stopping app:myserver id:0
PM2: 2015-05-27 17:16:17: App name:myserver id:0 disconnected
myserver-5 (out): Phantom broswer created.
PM2: assert.js:86
PM2:   throw new assert.AssertionError({
PM2:         ^
PM2: AssertionError: false == true
PM2:     at RoundRobinHandle.add (cluster.js:140:3)
PM2:     at queryServer (cluster.js:480:12)
PM2:     at Worker.onmessage (cluster.js:438:7)
PM2:     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (cluster.js:692:8)
PM2:     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:129:20)
PM2:     at handleMessage (child_process.js:324:10)
PM2:     at Pipe.channel.onread (child_process.js:352:11)
myserver-0 (err): Process disconnected from parent !
PM2: [PM2] Spawning PM2 daemon
PM2: 2015-05-27 17:16:18: [PM2][WORKER] Started with refreshing interval: 30000
PM2: 2015-05-27 17:16:18: [[[[ PM2/God daemon launched ]]]]
PM2: 2015-05-27 17:16:18: BUS system [READY] on port /Users/matthewmarcus/.pm2/pub.sock
PM2: 2015-05-27 17:16:18: RPC interface [READY] on port /Users/matthewmarcus/.pm2/rpc.sock
PM2: [PM2] PM2 Successfully daemonized
PM2: Be sure to have the latest version by doing `npm install pm2@latest -g` before doing this procedure.
PM2: [PM2] Stopping PM2...
PM2: [PM2][WARN] No process found
PM2: [PM2] All processes have been stopped and deleted
PM2: 2015-05-27 17:16:18: PM2 is being killed via kill method
PM2: 2015-05-27 17:16:18: RPC socket closed
PM2: 2015-05-27 17:16:18: PUB socket closed
PM2: [PM2] PM2 stopped
PM2: 2015-05-27 17:16:19: [PM2][WORKER] Started with refreshing interval: 30000
PM2: 2015-05-27 17:16:19: [[[[ PM2/God daemon launched ]]]]
PM2: 2015-05-27 17:16:19: BUS system [READY] on port /Users/matthewmarcus/.pm2/pub.sock
PM2: 2015-05-27 17:16:19: RPC interface [READY] on port /Users/matthewmarcus/.pm2/rpc.sock
PM2: >>>>>>>>>> PM2 updated
PM2: ┌──────────┬────┬──────┬─────┬────────┬─────────┬────────┬────────┬──────────┐
PM2: │ App name │ id │ mode │ pid │ status │ restart │ uptime │ memory │ watching │
PM2: └──────────┴────┴──────┴─────┴────────┴─────────┴────────┴────────┴──────────┘
PM2:  Use `pm2 show <id|name>` to get more details about an app
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [phantomjs-node crashes when attempting to scale behind node-cluster](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30496072/phantomjs-node-crashes-when-attempting-to-scale-behind-node-cluster)

Comment: Very much could be, but not sure.. in this case, specifically, this error doesn't show if the ```serve.listener(8888)``` is commented out.  It's very odd.  Seems like it could be a somewhat separate issue.

Comment: Could it be that each cluster instance is calling `server.listen(8888)` but as port isn't free it fails? Have you tried with a native cluster as you did on the other thread?

Comment: No I haven't.. let me give that a shot..

Comment: Hmm.. installed io.js and tried to run the same code as above and got the following error, all workers die:

```
/node_modules/phantom/node_modules/dnode/node_modules/weak/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:83
        throw e
              ^
Error: Module version mismatch. Expected 44, got 14.
```

Looks like phantomjs-node doesn't like io.js

Comment: This is getting WAY beyond my pay-grade: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28771245/module-version-mismatch-with-headless-browser-and-desktop-node